# Update image without flicker in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to update an image in my page from memory quite often. I've tested with loading it from resource directly (flicker) and from a pre-loaded stream (flicker). This is my xaml:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

This is my viewmodel:

```
this.loaderTask = new Task(() =>
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000); 
                if (i++ % 2 == 0)
                        this.Image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(this.buf1));
                    else
                        this.Image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(this.buf2));

                Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Image));
                });
            }
        });
```

Tested on Android. I guess there is some "standard" way to do this?

EDIT: By flicker I mean you shortly see the image disappear, then the new image getting drawn. I hoped a quick solution would be to put a placeholder at the same place as the one I want to update, but this doesnt help either, still get the default white background during load.

Comment: Use an animation to transition between them?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use WebView?

You can find an example on [Transparent WebView Load Animated Gif (Xamarin Android)](https://gist.github.com/wislon/a013a189dc245da2ffef)